# Interpet coefficient estimates with log(Y) in rdrobust package

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, robust, economics

[image]

1.I want to interpet the coefficients of RDD model above. The dependent variable is log-transformed. Should it be the same as linear regression even though I am using local polynomial regression with a selected optimal bandwith?
Should I interpet treatment effect as exp(-0.191)-1=-0.112 = -11.2%  ?

Then, the treatment effect on the response variable equals -11.2%.
2. rdrobust package gives us 3 estimated coefficients. Which one is more reliable on a small or large sample?